# Why has my manager made me the lead on a vital project over two older and more experienced employees?

Tags: promotion

Why has my manager made me (the youngest and newest employee in the organisation) the lead on the biggest organisational project over two older and more senior employees?

Comment: My mindreader device is currently broken; maybe you should ask your boss. That said, a possibility is that your manager plans to control that project closely and he will be the effective leader, with you being a sort of assistant.

Comment: Tx for your comments. I don't doubt myself or my ability to knock it out the park.  I was more wondering about common strategies that managers use and why they do so. As the youngest person in the entire organisation at 22 and with less than 6 months under my belt....I 'have' been told lots of positives and I know I have great skills, creativity and drive. It just doesn't make sense that my manager with only 1 month until D day (till major event is held), tells us she has 'withdrawn' and I am the one to drive it through! Especially when there are older, more experienced colleagues in the team.

Comment: Your boss probably plans to micromanage the project, how can he/she achieve it? Put the newbie in charge.

Comment: Be careful, there.  As I read it, you are to manage the *PROJECT*, not the employees.  They are not the same task.  Treat your colleagues as resources.  You purchase their efforts with clear requirements and respect.  Their manager manages them, you manage the project.

Answer (score 6):

There are many possibilities. Here are some:

- Your boss wants you to have some management experience. Managing people for the first time, especially giving instruction, can be daunting. These senior people are not likely to feel threatened by you; on the contrary, they will probably help you to be successful and gain confidence.
- The senior people do not want any management responsibility. This is very common in software development and IT, for example. A lot of people enjoy writing code (or whatever the skill is) much more than managing projects.
- The senior people are too busy, too essential to the project, to spend their time developing project plans, attending meetings, writing reports, or whatever tasks are required of managers at your company.
- The senior people are working on multiple projects. Your boss wants to have one person whose sole focus is on this project, to take responsibility for it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two logical reasons, totally opposite: One, he wants the project to fail, and picked you as the scape goat.

Two, he found that you have better qualities, better potential, or just more interest in actually *leading* a project than the older and more senior employees. There are employees who are very good at what they are doing and love their job, but who have no interest whatsoever in the managerial side of things. Making one of them the lead could mean you get a not very good lead, and lose an outstanding contributor.

Comment: While I don't disagree with the possibility, very few managers set up projects to fail.

Comment: @DJClayworth - there is the third possibility:  The manager wants to be the hero.  I've seen this before:  Subordinates without the requisite skills are put into situations they can't (yet) handle, and just before everything goes south, and just after everyone important realizes it, the manager "steps in to save the day."  Used to work with a guy that did this to his team all the time.  He had 4 people working for him, and only one was skilled at the job.  He tried to run out the skilled person.  The rest of us (different dept.) saw what was happening, but it was his team to manage, not ours.